# How to add or minus values when checkbox is checked using onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to workout with bus ticket booking platform where I want to get values added or subtracted when check box is checked. I use following function but it doesn't work. Can someone help me to solve this problem.

```
<input  type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='seatno[]' value='S1' onclick='addfare("100"); addtax("10.20"; addtotal("110.20"))' >
<input  type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='seatno[]' value='S2' onclick='addfare("100"); addtax("10.20"; addtotal("110.20"))' >
<input id='fare' />
<input id='tax' />
<input id='total' />
```

For this I tried following JavaScript.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var total = document.getElementById("total")
    function addtotal(caller,tot){
        if(caller.checked){
            add(caller)
        } else {
            subtract(caller)
        }
    }
    function add(caller){ total.value = total.value*1 + tot}
    function subtract(caller){ total.value = total.value*1 - tot}
</script>
```

I don't know how to solve this. Kindly help me to find a solution for this. I thanks all in advance.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't confuse JavaScript with Java. you are checking whether 'caller' is checked. What is caller ?

Comment: in `add` and `substract` functions you are passing `caller` but not using anywhere, so why passing it?

Comment: will you please rephrase your question and tell us what is exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Before I was using it like this

Comment: <input  type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='100' value='S1' onclick='addtotal(this))' >

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var total = document.getElementById("total")
    function addtotal(caller,tot){
    if(caller.checked){
    add(caller)
    } else {
    subtract(caller)
    }
    }
    function add(caller){ total.value = total.value*1 +      caller.name1*1}
    function subtract(caller){ total.value = total.value*1 -   caller.name1*1}
    </script>

Comment: script is wrong be clear with your requirements

Comment: Ok, let me explain it. I'm working with seat selection script. When I select a seat (eg., S1) i want to display "Seat fare, tax and total amount". If second seat is selected (eg., W2) I want to add Boath S1&W2 Fare, tax and total and display it .

Comment: When Seat S1 is clicked again (Uncheck) fare, tax and total should minus from the display field. When another Seat selected its fare, tax and Total to added together.

Answer (score 0):

The function call is incorrect:

```
addtax("10.20"; addtotal("110.20"))
```

you can't put semicolons between the arguments of a function.

Comment: Yes I closed i and tried, but even then I did not worked out.

Comment: addtax("10.20"); addtotal("110.20")

Answer (score 0):

I cant get your code. But with the understanding of your requirement here is the solution.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('check');
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if (this.checked) {
            add();
        }
    });

    function add (a, b) {
        console.log(a+b);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works great with single function. But here I have to use multifunction at same time.

Comment: Inside the if statement call all the function you need